# Differentiate between linear death process and pure death process

Tags: stochastic-processes

I am having difficulty (and my textbook is of no help!) figuring out when to treat a problem as a linear death process with death parameters $\mu n$h vs. a pure death process with death parameter $\mu$h. Is there anything we need to look out for in questions to signify which one to use? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does anyone else have an answer? I am so confused!

Comment: If you found Robert Israel's answer helpful, you should consider upvoting it as well as accepting it.  (Click on the little up arrow to the left of his answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it this way.  Given there are n individuals alive now, approximately how many do you expect to die in the next $\Delta t$ of time?  If different individuals' deaths are independent (which is the typical situation when the individuals are people or animals), this should be proportional to $n$ - there are more deaths per day in a big city than there are in a small village.  So then you want $\mu n \Delta t$.  On the other hand, you could have cases where the expected number of deaths does not depend on $n$.  For example, you might imagine a situation where deaths in an animal population occur only because at random times a hunter will come along and shoot one member of the population.  The hunter will not shoot more when there are more animals.  So in this case you would use $\mu \Delta t$.

Answer (score 0):

But, i think a death process with death parameter $\mu_n$ is called pure death process and a death process with death parameter $\mu$ will poisson death process?

Where $\mu n$ is linear death process?